# iPhone line break with i18n

Tags: iphone, internationalization

I need to break a string in lines so each won't exceed a maximum character count per line. I can't just break in the Nth character because I don't want to break in the middle of a word.
The application is internationalized, so since the text boundary is locale-sensitive I can't just break in ' '.

Is there any thing to help doing that in the Cocoa API?

I'm using OpenGLES, rendering text with textures, so UI components that handle that won't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use NSString – substringFromIndex:, – substringWithRange:, – substringToIndex:.

The indexes in these methods refer to symbolic characters, not physical bytes.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: The problem is how to know which index will break in a text boundary for the current locale?

Comment: Oh, so your fear is that ' ' is not sufficient. [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] sounds like it should work.

Comment: That will return a set containing a whitespace (' ') and a newline ('\n'). The problem is that not all locales use a whitespace to break lines, in fact, some locales dont even use whitespace (http://xml.ascc.net/en/utf-8/faq/zhl10n-faq-xsl.html#qb2), some platforms (like Java, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/boundaryintro.html) provide ways to determine the text boundaries for the current locale, so I don't have to code all rules for all languages. My question is if cocoa has something similar.